# Android View - manipulate the shadow

Tags: android

In a listview or many of the scrollable views, there are on top and buttom a shading effect.
I am not talking about the fading effect: It is the black color that appears on the top along with the fading effect.
Actually even if i am not scrolling seems like this black color will stay! please check the image

> How can this effect be removed? (maybe manipulate the color or sth)

http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/4035/badtl.png

this is a list

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the color of the fading edge with the `android:cacheColorHint` attribute, if thats what you're talking about and you haven't figured it out in the past 2 months - see [This post in the android docs](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html) for details.

Comment: @Sherif You also need to set the background attribute of the listview; I had my stuff sitting on a 'dark' theme and it still appeared even when I disabled the cachecolorhint